# Proving Replacement in $ZF^-$ without Replacement but with Collection

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

I was told in lecture, that in $ZF^-$ the replacement axiom scheme follows from adding the collection axiom scheme (without proof). So I tried proving it, but since I'm new to set theory, I need verification of my proof. Here are our definitions of these two axioms:

> *Replacement*: If $F$ is a function, then $F[x]$ is a set for every set $x$.
>
> *Collection*: For every relation $R$ and every set $x$, there is a set $y$ such that if there is a v for every $u\in x$ where uRv, then there is a $v\in y$ such that $uRv$.

**Proof of claim**: Assume $ZF^-$ without replacement, but with collection. Let $F$ be a function (in particular it is a relation). Let $x$ be an arbitrary set. By collection there is a set $z$ such that for every $u\in x$ there is one (and only one, since $F$ is a function) $y\in z$ such that $F(u)=y$. Let $w=\{y:y\in z \wedge\exists u\in x: F(u)=y\}$. This is a subclass of $z$, so by separation it is a set. But clearly this is $F[x]$, so $F[x]$ is a set.

I would appreciate anyone pointing out my mistakes!

Comment: Your proof looks good to me! (Though the formulation of Collection could be a little clearer.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This statement was more or less a side remark, that's why I did not put the formal definition.

Comment: +1 for correctly noting that the set $y$ postulated by *Collection* for $x$ and $R=F$ need not be $F[x]$ but can be an superset thereof. But wouldn't you rather write $w=\{\,y\in z:\exists u\in x\colon F(u)=y\,\}$ to stress the use of Separation? (This may however depend on the notations you introduced)

Comment: @GME You are right. "Bracketing" the $\forall u$ with the two subordinate instances of $\exists v$ like this makes the formulation even sound wrong.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I personally would do it the way you proposed, but I'm just trying to follow my lecturers notation to avoid confusion down the road.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, there's some funky scoping issues it took me a moment to resolve.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean precisely by $\text{ZF}^-$? Sometimes people mean power set is lacking, or sometimes foundation, etc. But it seems that you may mean just that you have collection rather than replacement, but with power set. Without power set, you cannot prove collection from replacement. See https://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/.

Comment: The formal definition for collection should be: $\forall R$ relation $\forall x\exists y:\forall u\in x(\exists v: uRv \implies\exists v'\in y: uRv')$. Furthermore $ZF^-$ is ZF without power set. But you are correct, I only wanted to prove that $ZF^-$ without replacement but with collection implies replacement, not the other way around. I corrected it above.